# How to take alert.prompt input and use it to manipulate data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, alert, native, prompt

I would like to use the user input in my application.
I have a bunch of "items" in the state declaration like so:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {

state = {
    toggled: false,
    items: {
        '2012-05-22': [{name: '9 AM - One 200 mg Paracetamol '}],
        '2012-05-23': [{name: '9 AM - One 200 mg Paracetamol'}, {name: '10 AM - One 500 mg Magnesium Tablet'}],
        '2012-05-24': [{name: '2 AM - One 200 mg Paracetamol'}],
        '2012-05-25': [{name: '9 AM - One 200 mg Ibuprofen'}, {name: '10 AM - One 500 mg Magnesium Tablet'}]
    }
}
```

I would like to take the user input and add it as another item name in "items".
I'm quite new to JavaScript so I'm struggling on how I can implement this.

Below is the code of how I'm taking user input for reference:

```
 render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.background}>
            <View style={styles.medicationHeaderContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.medicationHeader}> Medication </Text>
                <TouchableOpacity
                    style={styles.buttonContainer}
                    onPress={() => Alert.prompt(
                        "Add Medication",
                        "Enter time and name of Medicine",
                        [{
                            text: "Cancel",
                            //test
                            onPress: () => console.log("Cancel Pressed"),
                            style: "cancel"
                        },
                            {
                                text: "OK",
                                onPress: input => console.log("New item: "+input)
                                // onPress: Alert.alert("HI")
                            }
                        ],
                    )}

                >
                    <Text style={styles.addButton}> + </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
```

Comment: for those who don't know, this is react-native

Answer (score 0):

It is better suggested to use [Modal](https://reactnative.dev/docs/modal) to `Alert`. However, adding an item after receiving user input to the state is what's important. The item should to appended to `items` such that it follows a similar structure to its adjacent items.
Your `items` structure is as follows:
`string`:`Array[Object({name:<string>})]` 
You could have a submission handler function where you could validate user data and make necessary changes (non-mandatory), once you complete it, you should further create a key-value pair, with **key** being the current **date** and value being an array which further holds an object with `name` as the **key** and the user input as the **value**. This could be done as follows:

```
var date = new Date().getFullYear() +'-'+ new Date().getMonth() +'-'+ new Date().getDate()
var pair = {[date]:[{name:this.state.itemname}]}
```

You can notice that **date** is enclosed in square brackets indicating that it is a computed property name and not an array item. You can read more about computed property names [here](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/es6/javascript-computed-property/).
Once we have our key-value pair ready, we simply update the `items` state using `this.setState` for class-based components.

```
this.setState({items:{...this.state.items,...pair}})
```

Using the spread operator to concatenate new key-value pair(s) with existing key-value pairs.
The whole component would look something like this(using a modal here instead of alert).

```
import React from "react";
import {StyleSheet,Text, View,Alert,Modal,Pressable,TextInput } from "react-native";

export default class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
      toggled: false,
      itemname:'',
      items: {
          '2012-05-22': [{name: '9 AM - One 200 mg Paracetamol '}],
          '2012-05-23': [{name: '9 AM - One 200 mg Paracetamol'}, {name: '10 AM - One 500 mg Magnesium Tablet'}],
          '2012-05-24': [{name: '2 AM - One 200 mg Paracetamol'}],
          '2012-05-25': [{name: '9 AM - One 200 mg Ibuprofen'}, {name: '10 AM - One 500 mg Magnesium Tablet'}]
      }
  }

  setModalVisible = (visible) => {
    var date = new Date().getFullYear() +'-'+ new Date().getMonth() +'-'+ new Date().getDate()
    var pair = {[date]:[{name:this.state.itemname}]}
    this.setState({items:{...this.state.items,...pair}}) //append new item.
    this.setState({ toggled: visible,itemname:'' },()=>console.log(this.state.items));
  }
  setItemName = (visible) => {
    this.setState({ itemname: visible });
  }

  render() {

    const {toggled,itemname} = this.state
    return (
      <View>
        <View>
          <Text> Medication </Text>
          <Modal
            animationType="slide"
            transparent={true}
            visible={toggled}
            onRequestClose={() => {
              Alert.alert("Modal has been closed.");
              this.setModalVisible(!toggled);
            }}
          >
            <View style={styles.centeredView}>
              <View style={styles.modalView}>
      
                <TextInput value={itemname}
                onChangeText={this.setItemName}/>
                <Pressable
                  style={[styles.button, styles.buttonClose]}
                  onPress={() => this.setModalVisible(!toggled)}
                >
                  <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Add Item</Text>
                </Pressable>
              </View>
            </View>
          </Modal>
          <Pressable
          style={[styles.button, styles.buttonOpen]}
          onPress={() => this.setModalVisible(true)}
        >
          <Text style={styles.textStyle}>+</Text>
        </Pressable>
        </View>
      </View>
            )
            }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  centeredView: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    marginTop: 22
  },
  modalView: {
    margin: 20,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    borderRadius: 20,
    padding: 35,
    alignItems: "center",
    shadowColor: "#000",
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 2
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.25,
    shadowRadius: 4,
    elevation: 5
  },
  button: {
    borderRadius: 20,
    padding: 10,
    elevation: 2
  },
  buttonOpen: {
    backgroundColor: "#F194FF",
  },
  buttonClose: {
    backgroundColor: "#2196F3",
  },
  textStyle: {
    color: "white",
    fontWeight: "bold",
    textAlign: "center"
  },
  modalText: {
    marginBottom: 15,
    textAlign: "center"
  }
});
```

Note: The styles are taken from React Native docs, the above code emphasizes the logic behind appending user input to state variable and not on the UI of the application.

Comment: Hi Prajwal, thank you so much for taking the time out to answer this question with so much depth!! Appreciate it so much, I'll give this a go and let you know how I go

Comment: Sure, awaiting your response.